# Insert variable in quotes in template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

My variable in template is: `{% with lang=request.session.lang %}` and saves whether 'en' or 'ua'
In `<li>` I check whether current url is equal to /lang/:

```
<li class="{% ifequal request.path '/lang/'%} active {% endifequal%}">
```

But it's not working. I'm 99% certain that the problem is with it: `'/lang/'`

What is the correct way to parse variable in `ifequal` tag and in quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one more `with` here and construct the path with [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% with "/"|add:lang|add:"/" as path %}
    <li class="{% ifequal request.path path %} active {% endifequal%}">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: what if I need path to be /en/articles/(some_number): for example: /en/articles/2/  ?

Comment: @Andrew then, in a similar manner: `{% with "/"|add:lang|add:"/articles/"|add:somenumber|add:"/" as path %}`.